# How to copy the Gradient Fill from the SHAPE 1 and paste it into SHAPE 2 using VBA in Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have two shapes (Shape1 and Shape2) in powerpoint. Shape1 has gradient fill. 
And I wanted to create two macro: 
 - First MACRO, will copy the gradient from the Shpae1.
 - Second MACRO, will paste the gradient to the shape2.

Please guide me how to proceed into this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Format Painter is the simplest way to do that:

```
Sub PickupFormat()
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.PickUp
End Sub

Sub ApplyFormat()
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Apply
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But "PickUp" and "Apply" will paste the all formatting. Like font size, font name, border etc.

Comment: I just need to copy the Gradient fill from one shpae to another shape. Rest all formatting need to keep as is in the second shape.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Gradients is a complete mess if not even impossible. You will be better off catching whatever other properties you want to preserve, and apply them again after using @John Korchoks code.